# After login, there isnt log out option in front end

Tags: login, frontend, ce-1.9.1.0, logout

For some reason after upgrading to 1.9.1 or maybe before

when visitors logging in they can't logout

www.newtech.co.uk

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: may be their was some edits in the core file.do you have any backups of working site ?

Answer (score 7):

Your developer hardcoded the "login". I don't know how your code looks like, but it is one of two things:

1. You are missing this XML:

   ```
   <!--
   Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
   -->

   <customer_logged_in>
       <reference name="top.links">
           <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
       </reference>
   </customer_logged_in>

   <!--
   Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
   -->

   <customer_logged_out>
       <reference name="top.links">
           <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
       </reference>
       <remove name="reorder"></remove>
   </customer_logged_out>
   ```
2. You need to update your hardcoded value with something like:

   ```
   <?php if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
       <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></a>
   <?php else: ?>
       <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout') ?></a>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```